# Way to synchronize reads and writes in Clojure?

Tags: transactions, clojure, synchronization, state, stm

In a web app I'm trying to generate a unique thread safe id from a limited id pool. The problem I'm facing is that between reading and writing another thread may already have changed the data structure; this is why I have to resort to `compare-and-set!`.

```
(def sid-batch 10)
(def sid-pool (atom {:cnt 0
                     :sids '()}))

(defn get-sid []
  (let [{:keys [cnt sids] :as old} @sid-pool]

    ; use compare-and-set! here for atomic read & write
    (if (empty? sids)

      ; generate more sids
      (if (compare-and-set!
            sid-pool
            old
            (-> old
              (assoc :sids (range (inc cnt) (+ sid-batch cnt)))
              (assoc :cnt (+ cnt sid-batch))))

        ; return newest sid or recur till "transaction" succeeds
        cnt
        (recur))

      ; get first sid
      (if (compare-and-set! sid-pool old (update-in old [:sids] next))

        ; return first free sid or recur till "transaction" succeeds
        (first sids)
        (recur)))))
```

Is there an easier way to synchronize reads and writes without having to perform STM "by hand" and without abusing a field in `sid-pool` as a return value from `swap!`?

Comment: I think you have the right idea with "abusing a field in sid-pool". Except you don't need a field, just call (comp first sids) on the return value from swap!. (the first sid of sid-pool will then always be the just assigned id).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with an atom, by adding a field to `sid-pool` in the way you seem to be suggesting. I agree that's a *little* gross, but using `compare-and-swap!` for something so simple is godawful. Instead, use the atom; or a ref, which lets you return whatever you want from a `dosync` block while still being transactionally safe:

```
(defn get-sid []
  (dosync
   (let [{:keys [cnt sids]} @sid-pool]
     (if (empty? sids)
       (do 
         (alter sid-pool
                (fn [old]
                  (-> pool
                      (assoc :sids (range (inc cnt) (+ sid-batch cnt)))
                      (update-in [:cnt] + sid-batch))))
         cnt)
       (do
         (alter sid-pool update-in [:sids] next)
         (first sids))))))
```

Comment: @mikera is right, though - if you just need to generate integer IDs, just use an atom and inc it. I write this out in case you're actually doing something more complicated that can benefit from batching.

Comment: This was actually my first idea but I thought that `sid-pool` could change between the `let` clause (where it is dereferenced) and the `alter` call. So reads / derefs are part of a dosync transaction after all?

Comment: Yes. If you have a `dosync` that *only* reads a particular ref, then maybe it's an issue; I never fully understood that scenario. But this one is definitely an isolated, thread-safe transaction. If you're worried, you can try it with an extra `Thread/sleep` thrown in somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm confused about what you are trying to do but the canonical way to create unique IDs in Clojure would simply be:

```
(let [counter (atom 0)]
  (defn get-unique-id []
    (swap! counter inc)))
```

There's no need for any complex locking. Note that:

- The closure encapsulates the let-bound atom so you can be sure that no one else can touch it.
- The `swap!` operation ensures atomic safety in concurrent situations, so the `get-unique-id` function can be shared across different threads.

Comment: Yes, I should have been more specific; `sids` can be returned to the `sid-pool`. I'm doing this because I need the shortest possible unique number identifier per session.

Answer (score 2):

```
(def sid-batch 10)
(def sid-pool (atom {:cnt 0
                     :sids '()}))

(defn get-sid []
  (first (:sids (swap! sid-pool
                  (fn [{:keys [cnt sids]}]
                    (if-let [sids (next sids)]
                      {:cnt cnt :sids sids}
                      {:sids (range cnt (+ sid-batch cnt))
                       :cnt (+ cnt sid-batch)}))))))
```

Like I said in my comment I think you have the right idea with "abusing a field in sid-pool". Except you don't need a field, just call (comp first sids) on the return value from swap!

I removed the inc in the call to range because it caused the generator to skip multiples of 10.

And to return a sid to the pool:

```
(defn return-sid [sid]
  (swap! sid-pool (fn [{:keys [cnt [_ & ids]]}]
                    {:cnt cnt
                     :sids (list* _ sid ids)})))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this would leave the newly returned `sid` in the pool.

Comment: Well, it's a matter of convention, the pool of available ids at any time is (next (:sids @sid-pool)) instead of just (:sids @sid-pool). If it was not ids but referebces to huge objects there would be the potential for memory leaks but not there. It works.

Comment: Yes, I should have been more specific; sids can be returned to the sid-pool at any time. I'm doing this because I need the shortest possible unique number identifier per session - so a `sid` can not remain in the sid pool, unless I'm missing something obvious :/

Comment: re-using sids over a short period of time doesn't sound like a good idea. This is gonna cause you some pain, I suspect. Are you  *really* sure you need to constrain your sids like this? What's the use case? perhaps there's a better solution if we knew more about why. Is this an XY problem? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @sw1nn: it may very well be a XY problem; here's the use case: I want to establish an add-hoc communication channel (chat) between two users. For that, each receives a `sid`, then they exchange sids. The channel is established when both have entered the correct `sid` of their partner. So I need the `sids` to be as short as possible without collisions; I briefly thought about just using `(mod (swap! sid inc) 10000)` or similar for 4 digit numbers but this isn't scalable and part of why I'm doing this is to I gain a bit of real world backend experience in Clojure.